# how can I slice my list in chunks before I call a method on each of the chunk?

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have a `List` of objects in `Java`:

```
ArrayList<myObj> objs = generateObjs();
```

and I have a method responsible for sending the objects further, this method takes the list above as an argument:

```
sendObjectsFurther(objs)
```

I want to split the list `objs` so that I can send further objects in a group of five elements.

What is the best approach to do it?

I thought about implementing something like this:

```
public void sendSliced(List objs) {

    ArrayList<myObj> tempList = new ArrayList()<>;
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++) {
        tempList.add(objs.get(i));
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            sendObjectsFurther(tempList);
            tempList.clear();
        }         
    }
}
```

but I think it won't cover all edge cases, could you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Write a test to check all *'edge cases'* and see if hey are passed. If not, try debugging and come back if you get stuck finding the source of an error.

Comment: Hint if the last chunk has size <5 your algorithm never calls `sendObjectsFurther(..)` for it.

Comment: @randomuser1, also your TempList declaration is wrong instead of this "ArrayList<myObj> tempList = new ArrayList()<>;" it should be "ArrayList<myObj> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java 8 Stream API](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/divide-a-list-to-lists-of-n-size-in-Java-8/) for this.

```
List<myObj> objs = generateObjs();
int chunkSize = 5;
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

Collection<List<myObj>> result = objs.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
    .values();
for (myObj chunk: result){
    sendObjectsFurther(tempList);
}
```

Also, class names should start with an upper case.

Comment: That looks great!, but one question - will that work when the last chunk is < 5?

Comment: For example, if your list has 12 items, the last chunk will be of size 2.

Comment: I'm just curious, why use `AtomicInteger` in here while using normal stream?

Comment: I think this not necessary in this case but might be advantageous for a concurrent extension. I modified the example provided in the link posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use guava Lists.partition which will split into sub lists.
Example :

```
for (List<String> slice : Lists.partition(bigList, 5)) {
    send(slice);
}
```

The relevant javadoc link https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code, here each sublist will represents a chunk with 5 elements, So suppose I have total of 8 elements in my obj list, so first chunk will have 5 and next chunk will have 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            List<Employee> objs = new ArrayList<>();
            objs.add(new Employee(1));
            objs.add(new Employee(2));
            objs.add(new Employee(3));
            objs.add(new Employee(4));
            objs.add(new Employee(5));
            objs.add(new Employee(6));
            objs.add(new Employee(7));
            objs.add(new Employee(8));
            sendSliced(objs);
        }

        private static void sendSliced(List<Employee> objs) {
            int chunkSize = 5;
            final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            Collection<List<Employee>> subLists = objs.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
                    .values();
            subLists.stream().forEach( sublist -> System.out.print(sublist));
            subLists.stream().forEach( sublist -> sendObjectsFurther(sublist));
        }
}


class Employee {
   private int id;
   Employee(int id) {
    this.id = id;
   }    
}
```

Ouput Will be something like:

```
index = 0
[com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@77459877, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@5b2133b1, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@72ea2f77, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@33c7353a, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@681a9515]
index=1
[com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@3af49f1c, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@19469ea2, com.practice.stackoverflow.Employee@13221655]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one line to your code

```
public void sendSliced(List objs) {

    ArrayList<myObj> tempList = new ArrayList()<>;
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++) {
        tempList.add(objs.get(i));
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            sendObjectsFurther(tempList);
            tempList.clear();
        }         
    }
    sendObjectsFurther(tempList);
}
```

Which will add remaining items.